# How to add a edge to my toolbar [mxGraph - js]

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

I`m trying to add an edge to a toolbar in mxGraph. Vertex following the *examples* i can do it perfectly. But edges i can't do it, someone can help me? I declare a link style, but it doesn't work.

```
            var addVertex = function(icon, w, h, style)
            {
                var vertex = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
                vertex.setVertex(true);

                var img = addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
                img.enabled = true;

                graph.getSelectionModel().addListener(mxEvent.CHANGE, function()
                {
                    var tmp = graph.isSelectionEmpty();
                    mxUtils.setOpacity(img, (tmp) ? 100 : 20);
                    img.enabled = tmp;
                });
            };


            addVertex('images/rectangle.gif', 100, 40, '');
            addVertex('images/rounded.gif', 100, 40, 'shape=link');
            addVertex('images/ellipse.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=ellipse');
            addVertex('images/rhombus.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=rhombus');
            addVertex('images/triangle.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=triangle');
            addVertex('images/cylinder.gif', 40, 40, 'shape=cylinder');
            addVertex('images/actor.gif', 30, 55, 'shape=umlActor');
```

Comment: this will create a generic celll. `var cell = new mxCell(null, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);`
and this will make that cell Vertex `cell.setVertex(true);`
and this will make that cell Edge `cell.setEdge(true);`

Comment: I tried it, but when i put setEdge(true) i can't drop my shape at the graph.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit XML file of the toolbar you want to add edge to it, just like adding new cell to the toolbar

Answer (score 0):

Though Edge is a cell object, it cannot be placed in the toolbar for drag and drop. If your intention is to create connection between vertices, you can use the following in your code and check:

```
mxConnectionHandler.prototype.connectImage = new mxImage('images/connector.gif', 16, 16);
```

On mouseover for any vertex (source vertex), one connection icon (With Right Arrow) will appear. Just click and drag that icon to the another vertex (Target Vertex). This will create edge between two verties

Answer (score 0):

```
var addVertex = function(mylabel, icon, w, h, style)
            {
                var vertex = new mxCell(mylabel, new mxGeometry(0, 0, w, h), style);
                vertex.setVertex(true);
            
                addToolbarItem(graph, toolbar, vertex, icon);
            };
            
            addVertex("None",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/swimlane.gif"/>', 120, 160, 'shape=swimlane;startSize=20;');
            addVertex("Catagory 1",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/rectangle.gif"/>', 100, 40, 'shape=rectangle');
            addVertex("Catagory 2",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/rounded.gif"/>', 100, 40, 'shape=rounded');
            addVertex("Catagory 3",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/ellipse.gif"/>', 40, 40, 'shape=ellipse');
            addVertex("Catagory 4",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/rhombus.gif"/>', 40, 40, 'shape=rhombus');
            addVertex("Catagory 5",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/triangle.gif"/>', 40, 40, 'shape=triangle');
            addVertex("Catagory 6",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/cylinder.gif"/>', 40, 40, 'shape=cylinder');
            addVertex("Catagory 7",'<c:url value="/resources/js/examples/editors/images/actor.gif"/>', 30, 40, 'shape=actor');
```

//              toolbar.addLine();